# How to speed up list comparison / string replacement?

Tags: java, performance, comparison

I have a small program that reads input files that include C-like macros. The processing happens in two passes: the first one searches for the macro definitions and stores them, and the second pass searches for the macro calls and expands / replaces them.

This all works nicely, but it's time consuming. Currently, this is how I do it:

```
foreach token in file:
    foreach macro in macroDefinitions:
        if token equals macro.name:
            expand()
        endif
    end foreach
endforeach
```

In this pseudo-example, 'token' is a word from the source file, and 'macro' is the macro definition from the first pass. There's about 20 000 macro definitions, and 1800 input files, totalling in about 600 000 lines to process (and each line is splitted into n tokens). This means that the total comparison count is (count of tokens) * (count of macro definitions). How could I speed this up? Am I missing something, or do I really have to do all these comparisons?

For additional info, the tokens are Strings in String[] arrays, and the macros are Macro objects in ArrayList type of list. Could I speed the process up with other kinds of data structures?

Comment: C-like macros need to be defined before they are used, so you only need 1 pass through the file.

Comment: I have lots of files, and the macros are used cross-files. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `Map` that maps from a macro name to its definition.

In pseudo-code:

```
for each token in file:
    if this is a macro defininition:
        name, definition <- parse definition
        map.put(name, definition)

for each token in file:
    if map.contains(token):
        definition <- map.get(token):
        expand definition
```

(**Update** - You can get rid of the `contains` call and just call `get` and then test for `null`.  It is worth reading the javadocs to get a better understanding of how the Map, TreeMap and HashMap APIs work.)

Typical implementations of `Map` use either a balanced binary tree or a hash table, and have lookup and insert operations that have complexity `O(logN)` or `O(1)` (under normal circumstances).

Comment: Thanks! Tried it by converting the current ArrayList into a HashMap, and the execution time dropped from seven minutes to just under a minute. :) It will get even faster when I construct the HashMap right from the beginning!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to create a script e.g. in `Perl` that actually does the file processing and call that script from your `Java` code using [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).
Use the best tool for each problem.

Comment: I can't use any other language than Java.

Comment: @manabreak:Use java to call the script. The script will be just a file (could even be one-liner for an expert) and deliver it as well

Answer (score 0):

Putting the macro definitions in a `Map` will reduce the time needed to look up the macros considerably.

Answer (score 0):

edit: Klas Lindbäck solution would be better if you can add keys. If you cannot then searching algorithms as i proposed would be one way to improve search speeds.

You could add some search algorithms like [Binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) which would drastically improve search results

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `HashSet` containing the name of the macro definitions and for each token, check that it is contained in the set:

```
for(String token : token) {
    if(macroNamesSet.contains(token)) {
        expand();
    }
}
```

The `contains` method thake O(1) time. So overall and once the set of macro names has been created, it takes (count of tokens) time.

Comment: `Set` is an interface, thus how `contains` in implemented is not yet defined. 2 implementations: For `HashSet` `contains` takes `O(1)`. For `TreeSet` `contains` takes `O(log n)`.